# Showing Values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to show a list of values with a formula in MATLAB? So, I have a formula and value for `x` and `h`. Where `x` is `1.2` and `h` is `10^-20` to `10^-1`. So, I will have 20 values.

The formula is:

```
f1= 2*cos(x+h/2)*sin(h/2);
f1=f1/h;
```

So, I want to get 20 values out of it starting from `10^-20` to `10^-1` for `f1`, in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.` before `/` and `*` in expressions, as you want element-wise computation.

```
x = 1.2; h = 10.^(-20:-1);
f1= 2*cos(x+h/2).*sin(h/2); 
f1=f1./h;
```

Comment: The usual term for what you call "point to point computation" is "element wise *<operation>*", e.g. element wise multiplication and element wise division here.